# VIM regex pattern unable to search and replace characters that are between braces

Tags: vim, regex

I want to use regex to convert these:

```
<input type="text" name="salutation" value={salutation} />
<input type="text" name="first_name" value={first_name} />
```

into these:

```
<input type="text" name="salutation" value="" />
<input type="text" name="first_name" value="" />
```

So in VIM, I tried all of the following commands:

```
:0,$s/value={.+}/value=""/gc
:0,$s/value={(.)+}/value=""/gc
:0,$s/value={[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+}/value=""/gc
:0,$s/value={[^}]+}/value=""/gc
```

But I keep getting the message Pattern not found.  What did I do wrong?

Comment: You need to escape `+` => `\+`. See: [4.3 Quantifiers, Greedy and Non-Greedy](http://www.vimregex.com/#Non-Greedy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using special characters in the substitution, some quantifiers needs to be escaped.

This includes `+`, so you should type `\+` instead.

[image: Quantifiers, Greedy and Non-Greedy, escaping]

See: [4.3 Quantifiers, Greedy and Non-Greedy](http://www.vimregex.com/#Non-Greedy).

Answer (score 1):

Your regex was actually doing this:

`:0,$s/value={.+}/value=""/gc` = *Reaplce the string "**{.+}**" with value=""*

`:0,$s/value={(.)+}/value=""/gc` =  *Reaplce the string "**{(.)+}**" with value=""*

`:0,$s/value={[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+}/value=""/gc` = *Reaplce the string "**{X+}**" with value="" where **X** is a any of the charachter range inside []*

`:0,$s/value={[^}]+}/value=""/gc` = *Reaplce the string "**{X+}**" with value="" where **X** is not the charachter '}'*

So if you intend to use '+' as quantifier you should use '\+'. Otherwise, like in all of your patterns, an actual '+' is searched instead of *1 or more of the preceding characters*